# Postgresql service not starting after reboot

Tags: postgresql, raspbian, systemctl

I have PostgreSQL 13.8 running under Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye). I had to restart the Raspberry Pi it is running on and unplug it. After powering up the Pi again, everything seems to be running, but I can't get PostgreSQL to start completey. Previously, I started the service via `sudo systemctl start postgresql.service`. This now yields no output at all, it doesn't even ask for the password.

Running `systemctl status postgresql` gives the following:

```
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Tue 2023-07-11 08:02:48 CEST; 1s ago
    Process: 2232 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 2232 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 7ms

Jul 11 08:02:48 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Jul 11 08:02:48 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Finished PostgreSQL RDBMS.
```

I dug around and for the `active (exited)` part, I found several different discussions on stackoverflow and other sites. (E.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71659707/suse-service-status-is-active-exited-instead-of-active-running), [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1627335/nfs-server-active-exited), [here](https://forum.endeavouros.com/t/how-can-i-fix-systemctl-active-exited/18473/7))
None of these cleared up the issue for me. However, following some tipps from these threads, I looked at /usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql@.service:

```
# systemd service template for PostgreSQL clusters. The actual instances will
# be called "postgresql@version-cluster", e.g. "postgresql@9.3-main". The
# variable %i expands to "version-cluster", %I expands to "version/cluster".
# (%I breaks for cluster names containing dashes.)

[Unit]
Description=PostgreSQL Cluster %i
AssertPathExists=/etc/postgresql/%I/postgresql.conf
RequiresMountsFor=/etc/postgresql/%I /var/lib/postgresql/%I
PartOf=postgresql.service
ReloadPropagatedFrom=postgresql.service
Before=postgresql.service
# stop server before networking goes down on shutdown
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
# -: ignore startup failure (recovery might take arbitrarily long)
# the actual pg_ctl timeout is configured in pg_ctl.conf
ExecStart=-/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-redirect %i start
# 0 is the same as infinity, but "infinity" needs systemd 229
TimeoutStartSec=0
ExecStop=/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-redirect -m fast %i stop
TimeoutStopSec=1h
ExecReload=/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-redirect %i reload
PIDFile=/run/postgresql/%i.pid
SyslogIdentifier=postgresql@%i
# prevent OOM killer from choosing the postmaster (individual backends will
# reset the score to 0)
OOMScoreAdjust=-900
# restarting automatically will prevent "pg_ctlcluster ... stop" from working,
# so we disable it here. Also, the postmaster will restart by itself on most
# problems anyway, so it is questionable if one wants to enable external
# automatic restarts.
#Restart=on-failure
# (This should make pg_ctlcluster stop work, but doesn't:)
#RestartPreventExitStatus=SIGINT SIGTERM

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Running `pg_lsclusters` results in this:

```
Error: Invalid mode in /etc/postgresql/13/main/start.conf, must be one of auto, manual, disabled
```

Looking at the file with `cat /etc/postgresql/13/main/start.conf` shows this:

```
▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
```

which looks somewhat incorrect.

I have no idea how to proceed with all this information. Is it simply a problem of start.conf being corrupted? How would I fix that? Or ist it a configuration problem of the service? Do I need to make an entry in a pid file as some commenters mentioned in other questions? But what and where? Do I have multiple problems here?

I am still new to linux-systems and very confused by this, especially after the service ran without problems for months. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like data corruption all right. Get your backup.

Comment: Oh no. Just so I am clear: You propose a clean new install of postgreSQL and applying the backup, or do you mean that possibly the hardware is damaged and should be replaced?

Comment: I can only speculate about the cause. Very often, it is bad hardware. I don't know a lot about hardware, but a Raspberry Pi is probably not server-grade hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I cannot discard the hardware hypothesis put forth by laurenz-albe in the comments, as much as I want to, I want to make it known that I did fix the issue for the moment.

In order to do so, I manually replaced the content of the broken start.conf with this:

```
# Automatic startup configuration
#   auto: automatically start the cluster
#   manual: manual startup with pg_ctlcluster/postgresql@.service only
#   disabled: refuse to start cluster
# See pg_createcluster(1) for details. When running from systemd,
# invoke 'systemctl daemon-reload' after editing this file.

auto
```

After restarting the Pi, `pg_lsclusters` did not show any errors anymore. However, the postgresql-service was still in the status `exited`.
Then on a hunch I started the applications that connect to the database anyway and lo and behold, they did in fact connect and are working.
Sadly, this did not fix everything:

```
sudo -u postgres psql postgres
sudo: psql: command not found
```

So I couldn't log into the database and do anything administrative. However, after using [locate](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/locate/) to find the path to `psql`, adding it to `$PATH` in `/etc/profile` and creating a link using `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/postgresql/13/bin/psql /usr/bin/psql`, I can now log into the postgresql database again. I am not entirely sure that the modification of `$PATH` is really necessary.

This solution may be a bit hacky and not a long-term solution. Digging around the system revealed *a lot* of corrupted files that I had to fix by hand, so setting up the system anew seems to be something I should look into in the very near future. Still, I wanted to document my steps for anyone happening upon a similar problem.